# Deleting a node in a linked list left some data

Tags: c++, linked-list

i've use this function to erase element with a particular value:

```
    void eraseFromTable(ipTable * head,int sock)
{
    while(head) 
    {
        if(head->sockNumber == sock)
        {
            delete head;
            break;
        }

        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

This is the struct:

```
    struct ipTable
{
    char iPv4[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

    char iPv6[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int sockNumber;

    int ipv4;

    int ipv6;

    ipTable * next;
};
```

The problem is that when i use the erase function and then display again all the list
in the place of the node that've erased there's still sockNumber showed.
I've tried also free() function but it's the same.
How can i erase everything,pratically sconnecting that particular node?

Comment: Isn't this function going to break the linked-list? you are not linking the previous node with the next node while deleting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing two things:

1. Fixing the broken link from the node previous to the to-be-deleted node leading into it.
2. Reassigning the head pointer (which must be passed by reference / through a double pointer etc.) in case the node to be deleted is the head of the list.

Here's a fix (untested; also note I'm not really a C++ programmer so this may not be idiomatic - treat it as a general idea):

```
bool eraseFromTable(ipTable** headPtrPtr, int sock)
{
    ipTable* headPtr = *headPtrPtr;

    if(headPtr && headPtr->sockNumber == sock)
    {
         *headPtrPtr = headPtr->next;
          delete headPtr;

           // I'm assuming there can only be 1 matching entry; 
           // will need change otherwise. 
          return true;
    } 

    ipTable* nodePtr = headPtr;      

    while(nodePtr)
    {
         ipTable* nextPtr = nodePtr->next;
         if(nextPtr && nextPtr->sockNumber == sock)
         {
              nodePtr->next = nextPtr->next;
              delete nextPtr;

              // I'm assuming there can only be 1 matching entry;
              // will need change otherwise. 
              return true;
         }      

         nodePtr = nextPtr;    
    } 

    return false;  
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Basically i've to connect the previous and next of the node that has been erased.

Comment: @Azazel +1 on the answer. And Ani, you could pass the header pointer by reference `(ipTable *& headPtr)` if you want to join the throws of C++. The idea, regardless is spot on (though I prefer linked list management using double-indirection, as it shortens most algorithms down by about 50%, this one included).